# difference between p(y|x)p(x) and p(x|y)p(y)

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability

Is there a difference between p(y|x)p(x) and p(x|y)p(y)

If a joint distribution factors as p(x,y)=p(x)p(y) then x,y are independent,
so we can say that p(x)p(y) is different from p(x,y) in the general case,
and knowing that it factors this way gives some information.

Is there any similar thing if a joint distribution has been factored as p(y|x)p(x)  instead of p(x|y)p(y)?  As far as I know these things are the same, and it is just a matter of convenience or interpretation or application which to use.

For example, is there a sense that if you say p(x,y)=p(y|x)p(x) then y|x **is independent** of x?  I think this is always true.

Revisitng beginning statistics !

EDIT:  1) fix post based on Xi'an comment.

2) My comment: based on the comments from Henry, Xi'an, I believe the choice between these different ways to factor depends on the context, no other real difference. Propose that is the answer.

Comment: Using $p(y \mid x)p(x)$ instead of $p(x\mid y)p(y)$ is indeed a question of which is more useful in the context of the question you are trying to answer.  Assuming no zeros, they are connected by Bayes' theorem $\mathbb P(A \mid B) = \mathbb P(B \mid A) \frac{\mathbb P(A)}{\mathbb P(B)}$

Comment: Random variables are independent (or not) from one another, not density functions. And to answer the general question indeed $p(y|x)p(x)=p(x|y)p(y)$ (almost surely).

Comment: $y|x$ is not, and cannot be, independent of x *by definition*, unless $p(y|x)=p(y)$. That is the entire *purpose* behind the conditioning operator.